# How to get href value from a link using its class name with CSS selector in scrapy?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

`<a class="a-link-normal a-text-normal" href="/Art-Dutch-Republic-1585-Everyman/dp/0297833693/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=9780297833697&amp;qid=1574351815&amp;sr=8-1">
   <span class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal">Art of the Dutch Republic 1585 - 1718 (Everyman Art Library)</span>
</a>`

How to get Value of href using CSS selector or Xpath?

Comment: try with this xpath - //a[@class='a-link-normal a-text-normal']/@href

Comment: if you want the value without the href attribute, then use:  string(//a[@class='a-link-normal a-text-normal']/@href)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```py
    def parse(self, response):
        # iterate over all href
        for href in response.xpath("//a[@class='class-name']/@href"):
            # extract href as a string
            url = href.extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors example:

```
links = response.css("a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal::attr(href)").extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `response.css('.a-link-normal ::attr(href)').extract()`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following selector

```
a.your_calss_name::attr(href)
```